# Nesting error in Excel Formula - Changes to If

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I'm currently trying to record a macro for my excel spreadsheet, but keep recieving the message "The specified formula cannot be entered because it uses more levels of nesting than are allowed in the current file format can anyone help me out in fixing the formula to make it smaller?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Conductor + Surface",B3)),"Conductor + Surface",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("17 
1/2",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Drilling",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("12 1/4",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("8 
1/2",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Run Screens",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Temporay",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BOP 
Hop",B3)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Data Acquisition",B3)))),"Inter, Res, Lower Comp., & 
TP&A",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maintenance",B3)),"BOP Maintenance",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Re- 
entry",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Wellbore Prep",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Run 
Completion",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Install TH",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BOP 
Pull",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subsea Move Off",B3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BOP Run - 
Completion",B3))),"Upper Comp & TH",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rig Move - N and C",B3)),"Rig Move - N and 
C",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Install XMT",B3)),"Install XMT w/ Rig",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Open 
Plugs",B3)),"Open Plugs",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rig Move - S and B",B3)),"Rig Move - S and 
B",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Install VXT",B3)),"Install VXT","ERROR IN EXCEL FORMULA")))))))))
```

Currently there is a column with tasks that are too in depth, aka "New Conductor + Surface" or "ADCO - DG2 8 1/2" I want to make a new column with shorter names for each of them depending on certain words that are in the detailed column. I would then like to return an error if there is a detailed task that is not described properly.

Comment: Please describe what the formula's supposed to do and show us some sample data, because it'll be hard to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: @jsheeran I have just updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by modifying the setup in [this link](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-match-cell-contains) to a 2 column lookup table.

See below for sample:

Array formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX(lookupList,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,D7)),0),2),"NOT FOUND")`
remember to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when exiting cell edit mode.

[image]